# How do I prevent code in queued delayed jobs becoming invalid after a deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

We use delayed_job in a fairly high traffic Rails app, so there are always jobs in the queue.

After a deploy, when you restart dj, there is potential for the code in already queued jobs to become invalid. For example, if the deploy meant that a class used in the job no longer existed, the job would fail.

Is there a standard practice for getting round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a standard practice for getting round this?

Yes, multi-stage deployments (or whatever is the proper name for this).

**Step 1**: Deploy a new version of code that allows both new and old jobs run at the same time. For example, if you want to remove some class, make new jobs not use it, but don't remove the class yet, so that it's available to old jobs.

**Step 2**: Wait until all old jobs are processed.

**Step 3**: Deploy a change that removes the class and the old job version.

Note: you could implement step 1 by copying old job code and giving it a new "version". If you had, say, `ProjectJobs::Import`, you copy it as `ProjectJobs::Import2` (this version won't use class that you want to remove). Since they're different classes, DJ won't have any problems with picking appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that you have to:

1. stop all workers right after they finish their jobs
2. deploy changes
3. start workers

I think that in your case, [this code](https://www.randygirard.com/2014/08/08/zero-downtime-delayed-jobs/) might be helpful.